Send email via EmailMultiAlternatives sudenly stopped working
I encounter a strange error. The email sending stopped working since yesterday before all was fine. I did not change a thing at all.
Error message is:
  2024-07-11 09:35:01,147 share.email.service ERROR    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/deduu/./share/email/service.py", line 318, in send_email_from_template
    cls.send_admin_email(subject, recipient_list, html_message=message)
  File "/srv/deduu/./share/email/service.py", line 330, in send_admin_email
    cls.send_email(subject, from_mail, recipient_list, message, html_message)
  File "/srv/deduu/./share/email/service.py", line 279, in send_email
    return email_wrapper.send_mail()
  File "/srv/deduu/./share/email/service.py", line 91, in send_mail
    return_value = bool(self.mail.send())
  File "/srv/deduu/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/srv/deduu/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 109, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/srv/deduu/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 125, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 874, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.mail(from_addr, esmtp_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 539, in mail
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed 


Strangely the sending of the mail works with a testscript with the same credentials and settings but using this snippet
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

username = "info@test.de"
password = r"*****"
smtp_server = "mail.test.de"
smtp_port = 47999
receiver_email = "user@test.de"

subject = 'Test Email'
body = 'This is a test email sent using smtplib in Python.'

# Create message
em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = username
em['To'] = receiver_email
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

try:
    # Connect to the SMTP server
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as smtp:
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
        smtp.login(username, password)
        smtp.sendmail(username, receiver_email, em.as_string())
        smtp.quit()
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")


Email is used as follow (excerpt):
email_connection = get_connection()   
email_connection.host = "mail.test.de"
email_connection.port = 47999
email_connection.username = info@test.de
email_connection.password = r"*****"
email_connection.use_tls = True    
      
mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
    
mail.connection = email_connection
    
if html_message:
    mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        
mail.send()

Anyone has an idea?

Concentrate on the differences. I'd first try falling back from EmailMultiAlternatives to plain EmailMessage in the Django server. If that fails, did you execute the successful snippet in exactly the same context? (I'd wrap it in a trivial View in your Django project to find out).

Turns out it was a misconfiguration of the server, as someone changed something and dis not know what he does.
